# How to maintain focus on app window with AppleScript

Tags: applescript

I am trying to launch my scanner application using AppleScript.  I have it launching the Printer app and I know how to send the keystroke command but when the Printer window  opens it does not have focus in Finder so the keystroke I am sending is not working unless I already have the printer window open and in focus. How do I set the Finder focus to my window so it will hear the keystroke?

Here is my code:

```
tell application "System Events"
  tell application "Canon MX510 series" to activate
  key code 20 using command down
end tell
```

Comment: Does the keystroke go to Finder or to Canon MX510 series?

Answer (score 1):

Try sending the Activate command outside the System Event tell, that would be the standard method.

```
tell application "Canon MX510 series" to activate
my testAppRunning()
tell application "System Events"    
    key code 20 using command down
end tell

on testAppRunning()
    set test to 0
    repeat while test = 0
        log test
        tell application "System Events" to set test to count (every process whose name is "Canon MX510 series")
        delay 2
        --/*we do this even if active because it doesn't naturally come to front*/
        try
            tell application "Canon MX510 series" to activate
        end try
        if (test > 0) then exit repeat
    end repeat
end testAppRunning
```

Comment: This makes no difference for me using Google Chrome (I do not have "Cannon MX510 series" installed). Putting `tell application "Google Chrome" to activate` inside the `tell application "System Events"` block or not still activates Chrome and sends the keystroke.

Comment: With Chrome not running, OP's code works